# Remove actual code from a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript library that customers can use to script theire own extensions. Now since i wrote an eclipse plugin so they can use autocomplete and such features i'd like to publish this library but without the code itsself.

So only declarations and assigments should stay in the code but no real code. Is there a tool i can use to get this or do i have to write it myself?

Comment: You can’t hide it from the client as it runs on the client’s machine you can just minify it or decode it which can be easily encoded by some tools.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention, that the code does not run at client side or even in a browser. It's a server side scripting environment utilizing ECMAScript 5. The user should be able to implement against a "ghost"-library without any actual code, upload the code and execute it on the server where the real library is located at.

Comment: @PrakashKalakoti: He doesn't want to hide it from the client execution, but he wants to publish an API-only version of it for the autocomplete.